# What is the type of an async result?

Tags: android, kotlin, async-await, coroutine

I'm trying to create some coroutines (async) in a loop . I want to start everything in parallel then wait for them all to finish before proceeding. The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-adv) provides the following example:

```
    coroutineScope {
        val deferreds = listOf(      // fetch two docs at the same time
            async { fetchDoc(1) },  // async returns a result for the first doc
            async { fetchDoc(2) }  // async returns a result for the second doc        
       deferreds.awaitAll()         // use awaitAll to wait for both network requests
    }
```

but this requires that all the class instantiations be known in advance. However with a varying number of instantiations this is not practical. As a work around I found that the following works:
given a mutable List of class objects from class `MyObject` and `MyObject` has a method called `myDo()`

```
    private val mObjects = mutableListOf<MyObject>()
```

and ignoring error checking and assuming the list has 2 or more objects then the following works but it's kind of clunky and not very elegant

```
    coroutineScope {
    val pd = async { myObjects[0].myDo() }
    val dds = mutableListOf(pd)
        for (i in 1..numObjects - 1) {
                dds.add(async {mObjects[i].myDo() })
            }
            val nds = dds.toList()
            nds.awaitAll()
        }// end coroutineScope
```

What I'd hope to do was something like

```
    val dds = mutableListOf<Job>()
    for (i in 0..numObjects - 1) {
                dds.add(async {mObjects[i].myDo() })
           }
    val nds = dds.toList()
    nds.awaitAll()
```

but this doesn't work as the async result is a

```
    Deferred<out T> : Job
```

interface not a Job  interface. The problem with this is in the line

```
    val dds = mutableListOf<Job>()
```

I don't know what to use in place of Job. That is, for async what is T?

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

`T` in this case is whatever type `myDo()` returns.

I think you are overcomplicating it by creating the extra MutableLists. You can do it like this:

```
val results = coroutineScope {
    mObjects.map { obj ->
        async { obj.myDo() }
    }.awaitAll()
}
```

`results` will be a `List<MyDoReturnType>`.

**Edit:** I just realized, since it wasn't obvious to you that the type of a Deferred is whatever the `async` lambda returns, maybe it's because `myDo()` doesn't return anything (implicitly returns Unit). If that's the case, you should use `launch` instead of `async`. The only difference between them is that `async`'s lambda returns something and `launch`'s doesn't. Deferred inherits from Job because a Deferred is a Job with a result. If `myDo()` doesn't return anything, your code should look like the following, with no result.

```
coroutineScope {
    for (obj in mObjects) launch { obj.myDo() }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The documentation is somewhat confusing to me on this point. Specifically it seems to indicate that the various jobs would run subsequently not concurrently. I may have misunderstood the documentation. Your comment on the Unit was helpful. I used it to build a better version of what I'm doing which I have placed in Answer Your Question.

Comment: Any call to `launch` or `async` creates a new coroutine, so they run concurrently, whether or not it's inside a `coroutineScope` call.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from TenFour04 provided the key to my answer The following code works for me

```
coroutineScope {
    val dds = mutableListOf<Deferred<Unit>>()
    for (item in mObjects) { dds.add(async {item.myDo() }) }
    val nds = dds.toList()
    nds.awaitAll()
}
```

Comment: `map` is a simpler way to do exactly what you're doing, except without that extra redundant `toList()` call. The code in my answer does exactly the same thing as this code, except it doesn't create a redundant copy of the list. Also, if `myDo()` returns Unit, then you should use `launch` instead of `async` and you don't need to call `awaitAll()` because `coroutineScope` automatically waits for all its children to finish. See the edited bottom code block in my answer. It accomplishes exactly the same thing as your code here.

Answer (score 0):

Am I stupid!!! or what. After I figured it out, the answer is almost trivial. The best solution I found is

```
private val mObjects = mutableListOf<MyObject>()

coroutineScope {val deferreds = listOf(mObjects.size){async{mObjects[it].myDo()}}
   deferreds.awaitAll()
}// end coroutineScope
```

I like this better than the map solution as it doesn't create an intermediate Pair set